# DatePicker returns wrong year for Jan 1

Tags: objective-c

I have a DatePicker control in my app.  If I try to choose, for example, Jan 1, 2011, it returns Jan 1, 2010.  If I choose Jan 1, 2040, I get Jan 1, 2039, and so on.  Dec 31 and Jan 2 give me the years I select, so it is only a problem on Jan 1.  I have checked my code and I don't see anywhere where I mess around with the year.  Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
datenow = chooseDate; 
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; 
[components setDay:(int)daycount]; 
datenow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:datenow options:0]; 
dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:datenow]; 
year = [dateComponents year]; 
month = [dateComponents month]; 
day = [dateComponents day]; 
hour = [dateComponents hour]; 
min = [dateComponents minute];
```

Comment: chooseDate is the date chosen from the DatePicker.  Here is the code;

Comment: datenow = chooseDate;
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:(int)daycount];
    datenow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:datenow options:0];
    dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:datenow];
    year = [dateComponents year];
    month = [dateComponents month];
    day = [dateComponents day];
    hour = [dateComponents hour];
    min = [dateComponents minute];

Comment: In the above code, for this example, daycount = 0.

Answer (score 3):

if `daycount` is truly `0` like you say in your comment, then that's likely the source of your problem.  The `day` property of an `NSDateComponents` object should be in the natural range as defined by the calendar.  In the case of the Gregorian calendar, that is 1-31.  If the day is outside of that range, then units start wrapping around and you'll probably not get the result you want.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it made no difference.  I removed the daycount part of the code and just used the components, and I still got the same results.  Thanks for giving it a shot, I really thought you had the solution.

Comment: Dave is incorrect in the case where NSDateComponents is being used as a delta (`dateByAddingComponents:`), as it is in the above code. `daycount == 0` in this case just means do not change the day of the month.